# how can i get notification for every 5 minutes up to user has to launch that notification from notification bar in android?

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

I am new to android, I am developing an application for every day notifications using alarm manager and receiver, and notifications too. But now i am facing two problems

1. If the device is switched off , I am not getting any notification(I think it terminating  permanently) and
2. i need to show a notification every 5 minutes until the user launches the app using the notication from notification bar, but I am not sure how.

   ```
   public class AlarmReciever extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

     AlarmManager alarmManager;
     PendingIntent pendingIntent;
     int RequestCode =777;

     DBHelper helper;
     SQLiteDatabase database;
     SQLiteStatement statement;
     Cursor cursor;
     int datacount=0;

     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         String rec = intent.getDataString();
         NotifyMessage(context);
     }

     public void NotifyMessage(Context context){
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationTabs.class);
         intent.putExtra("Medicine", "Medicine");
         PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
           PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

       NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
           context)
       .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
       .setTicker("Take medicine")
       .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notificationtitle))
       .setContentText("Take medicine")
       .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Action Button", pIntent)
       .setContentIntent(pIntent)
       .setAutoCancel(true);


         NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) context
       .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

       notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());

   }
   ```

Can I please get some help on how to solve these issues?

Comment: Fixed up your formatting a bit. 
What have you tried yourself to find a solution to these issues? The problems you mentioned are pretty common, and solutions can be found quite easily with some quick research. Try searching for "Repeating alarms in Android".

Answer (score 0):

I have done a small proof of concept for your second problem.Please add the following code in your activity:

```
Intent notificationIntent=new Intent(context,DisplayNotification.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent=PendingIntent.getService(context,0,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.cancel(contentIntent);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),( AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES)/3, contentIntent);
```

Here is my DisplayNotification Service class:

```
public class DisplayNotification extends Service {
    private final static String TAG = "ShowNotification";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Intent mainIntent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification noti=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,mainIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
                .setContentTitle("Test Notification " + System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentText("Cricket news Dhoni is bold")
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.bell)
                .setTicker("match update")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .build();
        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

        Log.i(TAG, "Notification created");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Receiver Class code:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {  
    MediaPlayer mp;  
    @Override  
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.alrm   );  
        mp.start();  
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    }  
}
```

Please declare the receiver in manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" /> 


    <receiver android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver" >  
            </receiver>
```

Comment: its not working ..it did not get any notification when i change my code like this

Comment: Have you declared the service in your manifest?Also the permission for request <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
...

Comment: and i am also need to get message from receiver  how cam pass it through that code?

Comment: I have edited the above code above please check it@Latha.

Comment: i am not asking toast message ..i ll get a message from reciever ? that message i need to show in notification..once seee my code

Comment: Your code was not readable I have edited the changes please review it once and save it so that others can read it properly.

Comment: Nope the changes are not coming properly.Now approve it I have closed the brackets properly and changed the method name@Latha.I have also upvoted your question.

Comment: how can i approve?

Comment: if i have a from gcm i will get from receiver right? how can i show in notification if use your code?

Comment: If you are using GCM then fetch  the  device token first.Now from your server give a test message with the  the device token@Latha

Comment: yup .i did already.. then only i asked for this? how can i catch that message in your service code?